# Portlet like components for existing web application

Tags: java, portlet, html

I need to develop a page for an existing web application in `Java` that will include all kind of components that the user can enable/disable (these will need to be saved for future).

I guess that I need `portlets` but the thing is all these components will only be displayed on this page (not shared with other applications) so I'm not sure it's worth to complicate this using portlets.

Is there any other option?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess I want something like igoogle.com for a java web app (or at least a javascript library)

Answer (score 0):

There may be many ways apart from using portlets, following are some thoughts:

1. You can use `iframes` on the pages so they will be independent and will load on their own and you can style them such that it does not seem to be an `iframe`.
2. Or you can use `<div>` tags to separate the components and load them using `ajax`, if you have access to the components you are going to develop.

Hope this helps.